# Using JSON.NET instead of the default WebMethod serialization

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, web-services, json.net

In a WebMethod I am using JSON.NET to manually serialize my object to avoid the entity framework circular reference problem.

I have the following code:

```
Dim qry = From m In entity.Mediators _
          Where m.MediatorNumber = mediatorNumber _
          Select m

For Each mediator In qry
    mediator.MediatorRestrictionsAvailabilities.Load()
    customMediator = mediator
Next

customJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customMediator, Formatting.Indented)
```

The problem is that the result is not well formatted JSON and cannot be parsed on the client; it looks like this:

> {"d":"{\r\n  \"$id\": \"1\",\r\n  \"MediatorId\": 922,\r\n  \"AreaCode\": \"E         \",\r\n  \"PFCCode\": \"840       \",\r\n  \"FirstName\": \"Joe\",\r\n  \"LastName\": \"Smith\",\r\n

After doing some research I have learned that this is what happens when JSON is reserialized into JSON.

How do I do my own custom serialization without the default serializer getting in the way?

Comment: As I know ASP.NET web services doesn't offer replacing serialization with another one. You can only provide custom convertors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and [here are the suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512827/frustrated-with-json-response) which I was given. My solution was that I did not need to serialize the object again into json as it was already being serialized.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Chris thanks for the reply. You are correct but I can not use the native serializer because in my case it causes a circular reference error. I have to use JSON.NET to output custom JSON.

Comment: So you probably have to write custom .ashx handler and simulate service behavior yourselves or modify your entity code to not serialize circular references.

Answer (score 0):

For the circular reference use this approach:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  infoToSerialize, Formatting.Indented,
  new JsonSerializerSettings{ ReferenceLoopHandling =
  ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```